# How Add Custom Selection Fields color in odoo

Tags: odoo, odoo-12

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KPUIH.png)

** xml

How to add custom color in selection fields

**  Pythod code

priority = fields.Selection([
        ('clear','Clear'),
        ('urgent', 'Urgent'),
        ('normal', 'Normal'),
        ('lowand', 'Lowand'),
        ('high','High')],
        copy=False, default='normal', required=True)

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your question well, but I'll try to answer it.

In the kanban view of the employee module, we can see a red or green circle depending on whether they marked their attendance or not.

[image]

However this is not a selection field, but are two images that become visible depending on the circumstances. The code is the following:

```
<div role="img" id="oe_hr_attendance_status" class="fa fa-fw fa-circle o_button_icon oe_hr_attendance_status_green" attrs="{'invisible': [('attendance_state', '=', 'checked_out')]}" aria-label="Available" title="Available"/>
<div role="img" id="oe_hr_attendance_status" class="fa fa-fw fa-circle o_button_icon oe_hr_attendance_status_red" attrs="{'invisible': [('attendance_state', '=', 'checked_in')]}" aria-label="Not available" title="Not available"/>
```

There what they give color through the class, however if we want to pass any color to it, we must do the following:

```
<div role="img" id="oe_hr_attendance_status" class="fa fa-fw fa-circle" style="color: #f59042;"/>
<div role="img" id="oe_hr_attendance_status" class="fa fa-fw fa-circle" style="color: #42f599;"/>
<div role="img" id="oe_hr_attendance_status" class="fa fa-fw fa-circle" style="color: #9942f5;"/>
<div role="img" id="oe_hr_attendance_status" class="fa fa-fw fa-circle" style="color: #000000;"/>
```

And so we will get different colors:

[image]

I don't know if this answers your question, if not, please give me more details, what widget are you using for your selection field, or copy the xml code as you have it until now.

Comment: I am use 'priority'    Widget ="Priority"  color change but i try changing the color ,Do not change color in priority ,I have a requirement Red - Urgent

Yellow - High

Cyan - Normal

Gray - Lowand So How does it happen now...???

Comment: the "priority widget" shows 4 yellow stars, what else have you placed so that you get colored circles?